# facebook cant read og meta tags as not logged in

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

How can i solve this? When Facebook tries to read the" og meta tags" it can't as its not logged into my site, it gets redirected to the index.php.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

I use Facebook for users to log in (php sessions), I thought by providing the access token on the object url this would give Facebook access but it doesn't.

```
FB.api(
    '/me/namespace:request',
    'post',
    {
       test: 'http://mysite.co.uk/info.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&access_token=<?php echo $access_token; ?>' 
    },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solved this by checking for the facebook useragent and outputting just the meta tags